# What is exact value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n}$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

I would like to ask if anyone would help me with solving the following infinite series.
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n} = \,?
\end{equation}
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it has no closed form, it does satisfy the [remarkable identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n}  = \int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^x}.
$$
It is also equal to $\ln(3)^e$ to five decimal places.

Comment: Thank you very much.